# How to put a local repo project into gerrit?

Tags: gerrit, repo

I have a local repo project in ~/code folder, and I also have a gerrit in this server machine(assume its ip is 192.168.136.11), how can I move this local repo into gerrit because we want to use the gerrit to review the codes when developers push the new codes.

Comment: When you say "repo project", do you mean a single git or a multi-git workspace managed by the Repo tool?

Comment: I mean a multi-git workspace, we are devoleping a android rom on it.

Comment: Did you initialize the workspace as a mirror workspace (i.e. with `--mirror`) or is it a standard workspace with files checked out? Have you looked at https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#using-a-local-mirror ?

Comment: No, I just use repo sync to sync the android code, then I want to make a local server for other people, because some of them can't reach to google

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the repo's .git folder to gerrit's git folder

   ```
   $ mv -r ~/code/.git $GERRIT_HOME/git/
   ```
2. Restart gerrit

   ```
   $ GERRIT_HOME/bin/gerrit.sh restart
   ```

Should be updated now.

Restarting the service might require superuser priveleges.

Comment: `~/code/git-folder.git` should be `~/code/.git`, right?

Comment: Yes well by git folder I meant the folder that the project under version control is in, not the .git folder. Thanks though

Comment: I suspect that the OP's ~/code directory is a non-bare git and moving that into Gerrit's tree is bound to break something. BTW, I suspect flushing Gerrit's project cache should be enough to have the git picked up (thus no need to restart).

Comment: Possibly, but I don't know the flush command. Restarting is just as easy then

Comment: There is a .repo folder here, and the file and folders are: manifests  manifests.git  manifest.xml  project.list  project-objects  projects  repo. Do you mean I should put this repo folder into $GERRIT_HOME/git/